# Display specific earned badges as profile bling

Tags: feature-request, badges, information-display, user-card

What if we allowed users to show off specific badges, you know, like those holiday hats? (aka winterbash)

I know that we can already see a badge count for users, so, for example, other users can see that I currently have 7 silver badges and 30 bronze badges. But some of those badges are more important to me than others, and I'd kind of like to show off my accomplishments.

Like hats, users could select some number of badges (maybe up to 2) which will appear more promintently on their profile. Rather than simply the text, the badges, like real medals, could have different designs and images that in some way reflect the accomplishment (hopefully humorously). For example, I might show off my Caucus badge after I've voted (which might help to encourage other users to vote) or my Informed badge (which might help to advertise the new About page). I just earned my first Good Question badge, which I'd like to show off, and I'm working toward Fanatic and Sportsmanship.

In all cases, the ability to show off specific badges we are proud of would help to promote those badges and the behavior associated with them.

Comment: For SO I'd use my unsung hero badge... and for MSO my 3 reversal badges :P I really like this idea! +1. This also kind-of falls in place with displaying a users [citizenship level](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165179/replace-accept-rate-with-citizenship-level)

Answer (score 8):

> **Low-tech solution warning!**

The "about me" section of a users profile allows you to post whatever information you want to. Perhaps you could add this information there. Take some screenshots of the badges you want to show off and place them in some `<img>` tags...

> [image]

You could even wrap those `<img>` tags with `<a>` tags making those badge pictures clickable and more believable ;)

Comment: I went to your profile and tried to type a comment :P

Comment: @doo - Mission accomplished ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, your images do not show up behind my workplace's firewall. (imgur.com is blocked by corporate policy)

Comment: @cyb - that sucks :/ I hope without the image my answer is still understandable... Do you know of any other image hosting service that is not blocked?

Comment: My company is pretty thorough. :) I'll check it out when I get home, but I understand the gist.

Comment: @cyb - can you view the site from some 3G mobile device perhaps?

Comment: @Lix - *::dreamy look comes over face::* Someday, I will own one of those.

Comment: @Lix Legendary with `< 12K` means a **lot** of downvotes and bounties, doesn't it?

Comment: @dan... Awww shuks... you caught me... I'm not *really* 27 nor monochromatic IRL either :P

Comment: +1, but I'd really like the badges to show up in my user-card (so that other users don't have to go all the way to my profile)

Answer (score 8):

Going further on [Lix's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168247/245360):

Why not change the markdown engine a little so that we not only have

```
[tag:xxx]
```

elements you can use, which are eventually rendered as hyperlinks to the tag info page, but also have

```
[badge:xxx]
```

which will render the badge icon and link.

Comment: Of course it would be necessary to make sure that only those who have earned a particular badge can actually display it in their profile in that manner.

Comment: Unless you want to say: `Finally became [badge:epic]! Going for [badge:fanatic] now!`

Answer (score 1):

Today is My first day as a member of the site and I already like that idea. Just like in Call of Duty. Pushes some people to go for the gold or provides a quick and concise message of whose stomping ground it is. I vote for the flaunting of the badges. I mean bronze? silver? gold? not being flaunted. If users are not going to be able to show them off then heck I am gonna atleast start selling stickers. Place your orders here. jk. unless you really pressure me.