# View older questions in the close votes queue?

Tags: feature-request, support, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close

Is it possible to show questions from year 2009, for example?

Most of the questions I see in the close queue are new. It make sense to close the newest questions that are wrong.

But sometimes it's also interesting to see the questions that were added to the queue many years ago.

Comment: Yes, please. I'd like to know also.

Comment: This is currently not possible. You could change this to a [meta-tag:feature-request], though, and if you're lucky, they just might do it. If you're really, _really_ lucky. /grin

Comment: @Emracool - ok I added this tag

Comment: It also does make some sense. I'd personally like to see older questions dealt with (and not have them lingering around for a long period of time)

Comment: I tihnk filtering based on age and/or number of close votes and/or age of the oldest close vote or flag would be extremely useful

Comment: @psubsee2003 than dont scary to upvote for this feature-request :)

Comment: If you want this feature to be implemented, you will need to provide a more convincing argument than "it would be interesting". Try to sell the idea in a way that convinces developers to spend their time looking at it. (Note: I appreciate this started as a discussion item, but now it's a feature request it needs more editing).

Comment: @Duncan - its not the work Im paid for. I dont need to sell it :) If you find its good or some people who can implement it - very good. If not - also. I dont think that more text == more sense. The idea is clear and details can be discussed

Comment: @Duncan or if you have some details you cannot understand or questions - ask it please

Comment: @MikroDel Feel free to ignore my advice. I'm just reminding you that when an SE developer scans the *long* list of features that people want, they will prioritise ones that describe a clear benefit.

Comment: @Duncan ok I feel free now to ignore it :) But thanks for comment

Answer (score 4):

I think it would be incredibly helpful to have more filtering options in the review queue including by year or even number of total close votes, but that functionality doesn't exist yet.

While these aren't directly available from the queue, you can use the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to query the data. I didn't find any existing queries that provided filtering by year so I created a [basic query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/153012/open-posts-with-closed-votes-by-year) for posts with a vote to close as well as a filter on number of views, there is also a parameter for date filtering.

Based on the data available and filtering, I found the following:

```
+------+---------------+
| Year | OpenQuesVotes |
+------+---------------+
| 2008 |             3 |
| 2009 |            97 |
| 2010 |           287 |
| 2011 |          4420 |
| 2012 |         13654 |
| 2013 |         16885 |
+------+---------------+
```

This gives you some way to wade the data by year or at least gives you a start, while we wait for more filtering options in the review queue.

Comment: I [completely agree](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208235/178816)

Comment: While one couldn't hit the *queue* for these, if you linked to the question it would allow people to cast close votes on the question directly.  That would be possibly feasible for the oldest 3 years of data.