# Close Votes system slightly altered?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, review, vote-to-close

I was wondering if there was any change made to the Close Votes system? The number of unresolved reviews in the queue is day from day lower and lower.

I noticed that a few days ago, because it is abnormal that this queue is slowly shortening instead of growing. I don't have any proof but I remember seeing at least 101.1k reviews in the queue and now it is 100.1k and I would not be surprised to see it back at 99k tomorrow.

Comment: I don't know what has changed, but I love it :-)

Comment: Timing of the decrease correlates with the introduction of HATS. More people doing reviews and flagged posts getting much more attention.

Comment: Maybe its because of Winterbash and Hats?

Comment: This was also my first thought, but Close Votes require 3k reputation, right? Not so much users has that many rep.

Comment: My guess is that the review tasks are now sorted by the number of votes left to be cast. It would be great!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As discussed on chat by

Anna Lear

http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1683278#1683278

and Shog9

http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1683356#1683356

in the Tavern,

I would call it an issue with an operational side to it...

Don't forget to join the [SO Close vote reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)  where we keep an eye on the close vote queue

Comment: Nobody calls it a bug.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek corrected...

Comment: *9k aging, 5k droped*, we may watch the reverse trend now on Meta: "Why is the queue less than 90k, why less than 70k?"

Comment: @brasofilo ...and, finally, an announcement like ["Close Votes review: I'm going on a strikebreaking!"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208220/close-votes-review-im-going-on-a-strike), scored  +112/-27

Comment: Wait, so what was the change?

Comment: @KerrekSB AFAIK the close vote aging script didn't run...