# Encourage reviewing using a drop down list of pending reviews

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, vote-to-close

Been reading about the problems with the review system, and I noticed the following:

- Many users who have review privileges are **not encouraged** to make reviews. *I myself don't feel encouraged by the system to actually **do** reviews, although I have review privileges.*
- There is a **huge backlog** on the Close Votes review. The number is [*very discouraging*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208238/201738) when seen on the *Reviews* home page.

I think we can **take advantage of the new UI** to encourage reviewing better to those who have the necessary privileges. The review link at the top navigational toolbar could be altered into a **drop down** that gives quick access to pending reviews **and** alerts the reviewer of any new pending reviews that may be of interest to the reviewer.

*A mock-up of how this could look like:*

> [image: Mock-up of possible review drop-down]

*Things to note about the dropdown:*

- Tailor the list to the reviewer's **most prominent tags** (if reviewer regularly contributes most to [java](/questions/tagged/java) prioritize questions tagged with it).
- Tailor the list to the reviewer's **review habits** (if reviewer is more inclined to review *Close Votes* over *First Posts*, prioritize them).
- Only show a **manageable size** of items in the list, while having it scrollable (like the Inbox).
- Show a more **specific summary** like *"offensive or abusive"*, *"first answer"* or *"low quality"* in favor of a general summary like *"close vote"* or *"first post"*.
- Show the **number of flags** made on the post. If flags are not applicable, show the **relative time** of the edit.
- Show the **title** of the post and a **snippet** of the content to be reviewed, similar to the *Inbox* drop-down.
- Notify the user with a **highlighted number** when there's a new pending review waiting to be made. *This could be done via AJAX similar to how Inbox and rep notifications appear.*
- Periodically push randomly-selected **old pending reviews** to randomly-selected active reviewers, matching tags and review habits. *(This will help resolve the backlog problem and is similar to what the [Community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) user does.)*
- **Do not** categorize the items shown in the list. Let them be in a rolling mixed list so the reviewer is encouraged to scan and find interesting reviews to make.
- **Never** show posts from review queues the reviewer does not have access to.
- **Never** show the number of questions, answers or posts pending review (such as *113.4k questions in the Close Votes queue*).
- **Never** take the reviewer to the *Reviews* home page unless the reviewer explicitly requests this through the *"see all review queues"* link.
- *Alternatively,* the *"show all review queues"* link could be always visible instead of being the last item in the list. This may make it easier to get to the *Reviews* home page than is shown in my mock-up UI above. *(But I feel this is not necessary and may discourage reviewers.)*

The idea is to **shift the focus from** considering reviewing as a *back-end process* best left to the "moderators and experts" (or to those who have "too much time in their hands") **to** considering it as a *front-end feature* that is an *integral part of the site ecosystem* and therefore requires participation from everyone who has the necessary privileges.

I believe this will also help **shift the focus from** seeing *"113.4k questions"* and thinking *"OMG I can never bring that number down! `=(`"* **to** seeing *some* questions waiting for review and thinking *"Hey, there's a question I may be able to contribute a review to `=)`"*

---

***"Do I have to open the dropdown again and select a new one?"***  **No!** Absolutely not. Although it is a choice, you don't have to. The system can automatically move you to the next available item in the queue when you hit the usual *Next* button. If you don't like the next item, you can hit *Skip* as usual, or (again, a choice) pull down the drop-down and look for another interesting item to review.

The idea here is to encourage reviewers to **start reviewing**, by making it easier to visualize the queue and find interesting questions they can review - similar to how users can find interesting questions to answer by the lists on the home page (or the *hot questions* feature). It will also help **promote** the reviewing process as a front-end feature of the site rather than keep it hidden away as a backstage process.

But once a reviewer is *in* the queue, the normal review process flow is surely to be kept as such, with the added advantage of the drop-down availability. The drop-down will help the reviewer find another interesting question without having to rely on the *Skip* button.

Comment: I don't like task switching, reading your feature request I have to select first post or suggest edit tasks from the dropdown. What will the interaction flow  look like when I have done 1 review? Do I have to open the dropdown again and select a new one? If so, that would bring review time up per user.

Comment: @rene Answered you by adding to the post.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm still in doubt if this will drive more people to the close vote review queue though. If showing that number is the real 'problem', hiding it in the current UI should already help in that case.

Comment: The [number psychology](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208238/201738) is not the only problem. The bigger problem is the lack of promotion for the review feature, which can be resolved by pushing the queue to the forefront of the site. To quote that link, what something like this will help do is *"give them the tools they need to do so. Make the task seem doable, and people will come back."*