# Inline badge entry (conversion to graphic)

Tags: feature-request, badges

There are methods on meta sites when discussing tags to put them graphically into your question/answer (using brackets): [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

I am requesting that the same be implemented for badges: that it would be possible to use the syntax [badge:tenacious] and have the system automatically convert it to a graphical badge, like:

[image]

It would enhance the meta sites in particular by making them more aesthetically pleasing, though it wouldn't have a large if any effect on the main sites.

Comment: [Related.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168227/245360)