# Is average programming skill a minimum requirement to participate in SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Correct me if I am wrong, but StackOverflow expects some basic level of competence from the participants.It's certainly not for absolute beginners, who are likely to get overwhelmed in awe of the kind of questions posted on SO, the strict and unforgiving voting system,and the sheer brilliance of the ace contributors.

So should the unwritten rule be explicitly stated,that SO is not for absolute beginners and one is expected to do some basic reading on his part,prepare the groundwork on his own,do his homework so that he can be sure of what is he talking about?

It will be good for everyone,especially the novices who won't feel bad about being unduly overwhelmed by SO's rigor once they know it's for professional or motivated programmers and the **minimum** pre-requisite is **average** knowledge about a particular language/subject?

Comment: I don't think experience level is important in an explicit sense. I see it more as a result of the question quality we desire. And that's what I think we should focus on more. The [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page already explicitly states to do your own homework. And everywhere else the focus is on quality. I think that's ultimately a more positive angle than stating that "this place is not for beginners". I don't think such a statement would have that much effect anyway.

Comment: @Bart I ask that because I have seen beginners asking rather basic and repetitive questions in SO in good earnest,then being down-voted in good earnest, and then feeling bad about it.

Comment: I think the sole criterion for participation on Stack Overflow is the ability to write good questions. Even if you're an absolute beginner as long as you follow all the guidelines out there you'll be very well received. This assumes that you've done your research well first.

Comment: @SheerFish And I don't think stating that "This place is not for absolute beginner" will change that. Nor is it accurate. This place is not for people who can't ask quality questions. (Though admittedly there will be some correlation between the two).

Comment: "This place is not for beginners" is bad indeed,but it would be equally demotivating for a beginner/newbie(especially teens) when he comes in and sees so many people much much better than him and questions/answers that simply fly over his head.

Comment: @SheerFish Guess what, I'm in my thirties and when I come in, I see so many people better than I am and questions/answers which fly over my head. Welcome to being a programmer.

Comment: @Bart At your age if you find something difficult you are more likely to go for it with twice the determination and effort.Same can't be told of a teen once he gets spooked (Not all are good from the start)

Comment: @SheerFish You don't give them enough credit there. There are various teens here who show far more determination than that. People should be discouraged from participating when they continue to ask poor questions and show no improvement. They shouldn't be discouraged from participating because they are new to the game. In the end, all we judge is the quality of a question. And that, IMHO, is where the focus should be.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards _'you'll be very well received'_ There is zero guarantee of this. Most every question is a gamble in that sense.

Comment: There is a semi-guarantee. I've answered some massively newbie questions myself and seen more asked. Obviously not for everyone, but for me (and a lot of others), the sole arbiter is the quality of the question... see the arguments that went on [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165179/replace-accept-rate-with-citizenship-level) for example.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards A 'semi-guarantee' is utterly meaningless. There is _no_ guarantee. Most every question is a gamble.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Most of us who are familiar with SO may realize our mistake if our question is not well-received,but I have "seen" some newbies nearly tormented by the number of downvotes and "reprimand" they get.The touchy ones may inadvertantly get deep scars,even though no-one on SO intends that.LOL.

Comment: @SheerFish So your approach to that is "Don't ask anything at all", rather than "Pick up the pieces and learn from it"?.

Comment: @Bart If you are asking of me in particular,my approach is to build up a basic foundation on one's own first, through books and lectures.Only then if you fail, then it's ok to ask other's for help so that they can be sure you tried earnestly but failed.

Answer (score 5):

I think the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) is clear enough. Adding a specific requirement "not to be a beginner" or "to have average programming skills" wouldn't add much value. What are "average programming skills" anyway? A beginner can already find which questions are too simple for SO just by reading the FAQ.

Also, possibly valid but simple questions which a beginner might ask are likely to *already* exist on the site, so searching for them before asking them should be a must. "What is a difference between a class and a struct in C++?" has been asked several times, for example ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92859/what-are-the-differences-between-struct-and-class-in-c), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762085/difference-between-a-struct-and-a-class), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191782/differences-between-structs-and-classes)) and it takes 30 seconds of Google to find them.