# Is there a way to see acted-upon flags on Data.SE?

Tags: support, flags, data-explorer

I've been wanting to write a query to cough up a bunch of neat stats about a user. One of them is the ratio of helpful flags to declined and disputed flags. However, I can't find where I can get these counts. All I can see is the pending flags. Is there a way to either get the flags themselves (so I can count them) or the counts directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not.

Raised flags are private to the user and only accessible by/for mods. There was a time your flag stats were shown when you decided to run for moderator bit that is now [also gone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246357/exclude-comment-flags-from-the-helpful-flag-count-during-moderator-election).

I always assume good faith so I don't expect you to go hunt down or do a public bashing of users with lower than average ratio's. However previous rates were [abused a bit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate) and I can see that side here as well.

Just for completeness I checked if the [Stack API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids#order=desc&sort=reputation&ids=578411&filter=!9YdnSBV_a&site=stackoverflow&run=true) would return it. You'll find the earlier mentioned accept_rate. For flags there is no info, details nor counts.