# Additional info about received badges by candidate during election

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, election

We have tooltip for this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247138/260198

[image]

But it shows only received badges. Would be great to see here complete list of badges with additional hint if user has this badge.

Something like this:

[image]