# Unlock certain privileges earlier through proper use of current moderation actions

Tags: feature-request

I have an idea here in regards to the current situation with close/delete votes and viewing deleted posts. These are currently available only for high reputation users, and with good reason: The people using them have a great deal of power over the questions they moderate. This trust necessary is usually represented by the reputation someone has. This is done to ensure that moderating users know what they're doing, at least somewhat.

But there is also the problem (particularly on the trilogy) that we have more questions/answers in need of close/delete votes then there are voters to do this for.

I propose following change:

- When reaching 500 helpful flags with at least 95% of them helpful (disputed flags don't count one way or another, its helpful vs declined), 200 edited posts and at least 1000 votes cast, the privilege of casting close votes is awarded early (before 3k rep)
- When reaching 2000 helpful flags with at least 95% of them helpful (disputed flags don't count one way or another, its helpful vs declined), 500 edited posts and at least 2500 votes cast, the privilege of viewing deleted posts and to cast delete votes is awarded early.

I believe this would serve to add more people to the pool (and ensure those added to it are very active participating members of the community that already performed a lot of moderation) and provide an alternative path for people to participate in community moderation. I think that any person that hits these numbers could certainly be trusted enough to participate in this higher level of community moderation.

Comment: somewhat related: [Why aren't moderation tools given to people with a history of good moderation?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268077/839601) at MSO

Comment: I think that the numbers need to be tweaked a little. Do you have any stats on how many users have 500 helpful flags *and* 200 posts edited *and* 1k votes, but not 3k rep? I don't think there are much.

Comment: Maybe the numbers need to be tweaked a little. This proposal is not entirely set in stone. But number tweaking is only worth it if I don't get hit with a [tag:status-declined] within a day or so. I can compile some further stats on monday, but if someone wants to beforehand, that'd be even better.

Comment: @Magisch We wouldn't go anywhere with this without looking into the numbers ourselves. A proposal like this is only useful if there's a good chunk of users who are not being well-served by how things operate currently. We know there are *some* users who would like to be able to moderate earlier on, and could probably be trusted to do so. But are there *enough* to warrant such a large project?

Comment: Any reason for the vote requirement? I do more flagging and suggested edits than votes. I consider my withhold of votes as my right. Most of the time I'm not convinced that something deserves a vote, unless it is extraordinarily good or bad.

Comment: Request upvoted but not for the criteria used, 95% approval rating is too severe. I think if a user has earned 10K on at least two sites they should have the same privileges when they earn 3K on Meta. Admittedly, this is self-serving (I have 10K on two sites) BUT I also think it makes greater sense and it's easier to apply.

Answer (score 5):

I think the most important piece from your proposal is: *moderation privileges shouldn't be tied to reputation, but to a 'moderation' score.*

The beauty of the current system is that one variable determines everything: if you can comment, post images, vote to close, do reviews, etc. The down side is the very same: there is no way for medium- to low-reputation users to use their moderation skills to do a good job here.

I am not sure myself if we should introduce a *moderation score*, like the old *flag weight*, or something like that. What I do know is that we need to think of better ways to moderate sites and enable users to participate.

Comment: [citizenship level](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165179/165773)?

Answer (score 4):

The general idea of a moderation score, as Patrick Hofman mentions, I think is a good one.

How it's calculated needs to be very well thought out with regards to what you can do with it, and I don't think the system you propose is good enough for that. Helpful flags is all very well, but those are any flags at all. If you want to award the close privilege, before the rep requirement, I'd be loath to do that with some evidence that the user has a decent record of closing - perhaps helpful *close* flags is a better number. edits and votes have nothing to do with closing apart from to demonstrate that a user is committed to the site, which is good, but I'd want to see evidence directly for the privilege.

Likewise with awarding the delete privilege. I'd be looking at helpful not an answer flags to measure moderation score in that regard, rather than just plain flags.

Comment: Conversely, review and edit suspensions (especially manually mod-imposed suspensions) should decrease one's "moderator ability" score.