# Add a link to the participation tab

Tags: feature-request, participation

There is a hidden tab on all sites, showing participation. It can be accessed by going to the SE site and adding this to the end: `users?tab=Participation`. This then sorts users into the amount they have participated on that site.

I am guessing this is calculated by:

- reputation
- posts
- edits
- flags?

Can we add a link to this tab so users can visit it?

This could help with:

- it being easier to see who contributes the most in that community
- it's existence could be made known to more users

It's only a tab link, it can't be that hard to add it.

Comment: It's not obvious what it's measuring eg: top listed user on WB.SE has a reputation of 101 (unable to down-vote), has never asked or answered, and over their three plus years has roughly similar flag and vote-count to myself (11.7k user) - yet I'm not listed in the first seven pages of results. Could we establish what it measures before requesting a tab?

Comment: @WeareMonica. they have a lot of votes though

Comment: True, fewer than [Willk](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/31698/willk?tab=topactivity) who appears 8th on the list, who doesn't have as many flags - so maybe an arcane calculation involving multiple factors. There's also the time-period to consider.

Comment: related (possibly a duplicate): [Replace accept rate with citizenship level](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165179/165773)