# What does the participation tab measure?

Tags: discussion, support, participation

As suggested from:

- [Add a link to the participation tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337805/add-a-link-to-the-participation-tab)

> It's not obvious what it's measuring eg: top listed user on WB.SE has a reputation of 101 (unable to down-vote), has never asked or answered, and over their three plus years has roughly similar flag and vote-count to myself (11.7k user) - yet I'm not listed in the first seven pages of results. Could we establish what it measures before requesting a tab?

There is a hidden tab on all sites, showing participation. It can be accessed by going to the SE site and adding this to the end: `users?tab=Participation`. This then sorts users into the amount they have participated on that site.

I am guessing this is calculated by:

- reputation
- posts
- edits
- votes
- flags?

What exactly does this tab measure?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Participation Oh hi there! I feel it is the "actions taken" which can be seen in [activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=activity&sort=all), per unit time. I don't know, over what time it measures it. @MathieuGuindon Votes makes a very weak case for participation. They are not present in "All actions" either.

Comment: @ankii and yet there's a "Voters" tab

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Okay, still, the rest of the comment remains.

Comment: Yeah, that's a valid duplicate...the tab *is* linked from per-site metas, and from what I can tell, the same definition is used for the unlinked tab on main sites.